# Why can't I set a variable in a prepared statement in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm running a script to insert some data in a MySQL database, and it runs properly in the MySQL workbench. However, when I try to run it from Java via the JDBC, I get an error. The script is:

```
INSERT INTO `pa_record` (`username`, `pa_record_type`, `record_time`) VALUES (?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
SET @record_id := 1;
INSERT INTO `pa_crud` (`pa_record_id`, `table_name`) VALUES (@record_id, ?);
```

The error I get from the JDBC is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @record_id := 1;
>   INSERT INTO `pa_crud` (`pa_record_id`, `table_name`) VALUES' at line 2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many (most?) database access libraries do not allow multiple statements in a single execute; those that do, usually need to have the feature activated with a setting change. *It's likely not complaining about the SET, but that you had anything after the end of the first query at all.*

Comment: 100% correct, thanks. The setting can be set in the connection string, with allowMultiQueries=true